# convert to BLOB to XML - XML parsing: illegal xml character

Tags: sql, xml

I have a blob column in the database column name is energy.
The query is:

```
    select 
CONVERT(xml,(CONVERT(varbinary(max),energy)))
from tableenergy
```

but i am getting the error "XML parsing: illegal xml character"

I check with TOAD the column where XML in ACII has things like 
"Name="Mois pr??c??dent"

If I check in TOAD with UTF 8 looks better
"Name="Mois précédent"

I want to make a query to avoid that error, I guess that is because the convertion is done in ASCII, how can convert the BLOB column in XML in a query?

Answer (score 0):

you need to convert your xml to UTF 16 or Unicode the xml parser cannot read the diacritic characters (ie: é è). Those symbols are not in the ASCII chart try something like:

```
select value(x).getBlobVal(energy_charset_id('AL32UTF8')) from tableenergy
```

Comment: But i am still geting this error with that select "'value' is not a recognized built-in function name."

Answer (score 0):

Since we don't know which type of database you are on (Oracle, mySQL, Postgre, etc.) this is a general solution.

In order for the conversion to truly work, you need to ensure that you are NOT using any values that the XML Parsing function won't understand.

Try this:

```
SELECT CONVERT(energy USING utf8)
FROM tableenergy
```

Comment: it is SQL Server and your query gives me syntax error